# Change textbox highlight color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I want to change the highlight color of the textbox in bootstrap. Is it possible? Im using bootstrap to my login form. Im new to html and css and also to bootstrap. Please give me a clue on how to do it.

Comment: Yes, it is very possible, simply write a CSS rule that overrides the default bootstrap styles

Comment: But i don't know what element i will override.

Comment: Use your browsers inspector to view the rules applied to that element, then change the `:focus` pseudo class to fit your need. If you only want to change the theme on certain elements, use a class

Comment: You also need to post your demo code, and a jsfiddle would be nice

Comment: Please post your code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I click on an bootstrap input in the browser, right click, choose "Inspect Element ...", on the right I see "Rules" or "Styles" for the CSS.  One of them is as follows:

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

The colors (both the hex #66afe9 and the rgba(102,175,233,.6)) in there are what make it blue, so you would need to change those values (though I don't know enough about bootstrap to know if you're probably preprocessing the CSS and would therefore change some variable value somewhere instead of plain CSS).