# Html Css change Date input highlight color

Tags: html, css, date, web, input

I have an input of type date in my page and I want to change the color of the highlight inside of it and I don't know if there are css selector for that.

Here's an image of what i'm talking about :

[image]

Thank you for your concerned! :)

**EDIT**

here's what i'm trying to do:

[image]  TO [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change textbox highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095442/change-textbox-highlight-color)

Comment: @jimboweb It's not the same thing. The post talk about the border focus color but here i'm talking about the text highlight color

Comment: Just use background-color. Not that hard to figure it out

Comment: Okay, then try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258647/changing-the-highlight-color-when-selecting-text-in-an-html-text-input

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try adding something like this to your question, so that others could understand you better. https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1442/

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar it doesnt work too

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I find a 'non-webkit' solution I will update this.

Credit to [dboskovic](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/1877#issuecomment-15088274) on the Zurb GitHub repo:

> ```
> input::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:focus,
> input::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:focus,
> input::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:focus {
>     background-color: red;
>     color: white;
>     outline: none;
> }
> ```

Comment: You don't want to change the color to the same color as the background-color, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I made my date input as text box so ::selection can work on it. This works for me in Chrome and Edge, but I noticed when combined with -moz in the same statement it stops working.

```
<style>
    #myInput {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 144); 
    }
    #myInput::selection {
        background-color: rgba(248, 90, 192, 0.56); 
    }
    #myInput::-moz-selection {
        background-color: rgba(248, 90, 192, 0.56); 
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" value="Test input text" />
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's trying to style the date input and your solution doesn't work on that type of input.

Answer (score -1):

it might be helpful,changed the following css entry in bootstrap.css

```css
textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {   
  border-color: rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6);
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's trying to style the date input and your solution doesn't work on that type of input.